# How to properly position img with resize handlers?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a container which will contain an image with horizontal and vertical resizers. Additionally, I would like to be able to position the figure within this container (left, right, center, float left, float right). Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.horizontal-resize-handle,
.vertical-resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: blue;
}

.horizontal-resize-handle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.vertical-resize-handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <span class="span">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://www.copahost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/imgsize2.png" width=25%>

      <div class="horizontal-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="vertical-resize-handle"></div>
   
    </div>
  </span>
</article>
```

Unfortunately, the handlers don't fit the image (cover the entire page) and the positioning using `justify-content` in the `container` class doesn't work too. What should I change?

Comment: _"What should I change?"_ - the invalid HTML, first of all. You can not nest `div` into `span`.

Comment: Why not? Have a look at this site https://sereneinserenade.github.io/tiptap-media-resize/, and look how the image looks like in the dev tools.  There is a div into a span,

Comment: _"Why not?"_ - because the _rules_ of HTML say so? [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span#technical_summary) has "Permitted content: [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content)", and the latter does not include `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot nest a block-element inside a inline-element. Block elements take up the entire width of the page, while inline-elements don't.

Secondly, in your html, you set the width of the image to 25%, so that should be the width of your `.vertical-resize-handle`. For your `.horizontal-resize-handle`, you could set how far it should be. Whether from the left or from the right is your choice, in this situation, how far from the left would be easier. You need to push the `.horizontal-resize-handle` to the left, by the width of the image: `left: 25%;`, but that pushes the left edge of the handle to the right edge of the image. But we want the right edges to be on top of each other. So you minus the width of the handle from it: `left: calc(25% - 0.5rem) /* 0.5rem is the width of the resize handle */`

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}

.img-container {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position:relative
}
.horizontal-resize-handle,
.vertical-resize-handle {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 50;
        opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: blue;
}

.horizontal-resize-handle {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0.5rem;
        top: 0;
        left: calc(25% - 0.5rem);
        cursor: col-resize;
}

.vertical-resize-handle {
        width: 25%;
        height: 0.5rem;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <div class="span">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://www.copahost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/imgsize2.png" width=25%>

      <div class="horizontal-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="vertical-resize-handle"></div>
   
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

If you want the bars outside of the image, then just increase the distance to the image by the width of the handles:

##### horizontal-resize-handle:

`left: calc(50% - 0.5rem + 0.5rem);` "-" and "+" would cancel out and it would become `left: 50%;`

##### vertical-resize-handle:

For your vertical-handle you use `bottom: 0;`, since you use `bottom`, we can't add the height of the handle. Since we would do `top: currentDistance + 0.5rem` for `top:` we need to do the inverse if we use bottom, which is `bottom: currentDistance - 0.5rem`. And if `currentDistance` is `0`, then we can just write `-0.5rem`

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}

.img-container {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position:relative
}
.horizontal-resize-handle,
.vertical-resize-handle {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 50;
        opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: blue;
}

.horizontal-resize-handle {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0.5rem;
        top: 0;
        left: 25%;
        cursor: col-resize;
}

.vertical-resize-handle {
        width: 25%;
        height: 0.5rem;
        bottom: -0.5rem;
        left: 0;
        cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <div class="span">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://www.copahost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/imgsize2.png" width=25%>

      <div class="horizontal-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="vertical-resize-handle"></div>
   
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

[This](https://blog.devgenius.io/css-display-flex-vs-block-inline-and-inline-block-explained-5fa588a3a960) might be useful, if you are looking into the differences between `flex`, `inline` and `block`.

Comment: @Mercer, I added a different scenario, incase something else is what you wanted!

Comment: Thank you, it works :) One more question. What I wanted to do is to repliace behaviour from here  https://sereneinserenade.github.io/tiptap-media-resize/, Have a look at  the image in the devtools - it and resizers are contained within the div which is contained inside the span. I like this idea but I'm not able to repliace it. It seems that there `width: fit-content` is used to fit the resizers but it doesnt work in my case

Comment: @Mercer I don't know how `width: fit-content` works in CSS. CSS is currently the language, I am worst at. :P Sorry that I couldn't help you

Comment: @Mercer, I heard of a jQuery plugin called jQuery resize, that you can use to resize images, and so on. I haven't tried it myself, but maybe it would work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.horizontal-resize-handle,
.vertical-resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: blue;
}

.horizontal-resize-handle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.vertical-resize-handle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

/* Positioning classes */
.position-left {
  left: 0;
}

.position-right {
  right: 0;
}

.position-center {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <span class="span">
    <div class="img-container position-center">
      <img src="https://www.copahost.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/imgsize2.png" width="25%">
      <div class="horizontal-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="vertical-resize-handle"></div>
    </div>
  </span>
</article>
```